# jquery not opening any window to select file in android native browser

Tags: android, jquery

I am trying to upload a file through HTML and jQuery. It's working fine on desktop browsers but on mobile it works fine in chrome browser but in the Android native browser its not opening any windows to select a file. I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy Grand with Android version: 4.1.

```
<div class="hiddenInputFile">
    <form:input type="file" id="fileInput" path="imagePath" accept="image/*" />
</div>
<a id ="addPhotoBtn" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn_grey">
    Add Photo
</a>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("#addPhotoBtn").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fileInput:hidden").trigger('click');
      });
    });

// other stuff...
```

Comment: Is it this: `});});`? You have a duplicate `});`, but only have 1 `({`

Comment: Sorry, missed the function(), edited it